# JQuery - AfterDocumentReady?

Tags: jquery

Is there an event that I can register that will be executed after all `$(document).ready` scripts are executed? I've got a piece of code that needs to be executed after the whole page is fully loaded (also the jQuery scripts). Is this possible?

I need to register this in a script file, so can't put the function at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to attach an event to when all of the scripts are executed and run. There is no hook for for your particular case in javascript because scripts can have very different logic like being loaded asynchronously, having timeouts, etc. But there is an event that is fired when all of the scripts are loaded in the browser (but still they are not executed):

```
$(window).load(function () {
    // your code is here
});
```

will be executed after the whole page including scripts and graphics will be loaded. Though, this doesn't mean the scripts are actually executed.
But, if your scripts only contain the logic that requires immediate actions like

```
alert('Hi!');
```

then those will be executed before `$(window).load()`

Comment: NO -- the `load` method is an ajax call that loads the content from a URL into the page -- it won't do what you think -- look [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/). `window.onload` will do what you want

Comment: YES! Read the first comment at http://api.jquery.com/load-event/ @greengit. There are 2 types of load() in jQuery — the event and, as you mention, the method.

Comment: i don't get it -- how does the comment solve the current problem ?

Comment: @greengit, the comment solves the problem in the way that $(window).load() is not "an ajax call that loads the content from a URL into the page". But is exactly what Kees needs — event that is fired after all of the scripts and artifacts are loaded into the page.

Comment: +1 OK i got it -- i was looking at the wrong page -- my fault -- sorry!

Comment: So the `window.load` is executed after all the `document.load` functions are executed?

Comment: I see the confusion @greengit. It was my fault to point to the wrong place. When I said 'first comment', I meant 'first example' on that page. Excuse me, the *first comment* doesn't help here indeed :)

Comment: @Kees, you can not attach load() event on $(document). Only elements that are associated with a URL have this event. $(document) is not one of those, while $(window) is. But if you meant $(document).ready(), then yes, $(window).load() will be executed after $(document).ready().

Comment: @spliter... I don't understand... everybody uses `$(document).ready(function(){});` to load startup scripts, right? Are we talking about the same thing?

Comment: @Kees, $(document).ready() is fired when the DOM is loaded, but not necessary scripts are at this point. $(window).load() is fired when all the scrips, styles and images are loaded.

Comment: What is the definition of a 'loaded script'? Does it mean the file is available or that the file has been executed? For example... if I have a script that says `alert('hi!');`... wil it be executed before the `window.load`?

Comment: @Kees, I see what you mean. I have extended my response to highlight that particular case.

Answer (score 0):

The `$(document).ready` scripts are executed in order. You can simply add a `$(document).ready` handler to the bottom of the page.

**EDIT**

Note that this assumes your not using `async` script loading

**EDIT**

If you need to include the function in a script file and the script file cannot somehow be the last one to load you could try to append the ready function on the fly (untested):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').append('<script>$(document).ready(...);</script>');

});
```

Comment: I need to register this in a script file, so can't put the function at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @Juhana, that's not possible, because I can't garantee it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $(document).ready is executed after DOM loading complete

Comment: Yeah, but I need to execute this function after all other `document.ready` methods are done executing.

Comment: but why you want to do this?....then just call some function at the end of document.ready function...

Comment: @Tushar You're assuming he has only one of them. The question implies he has many. The functions may also be in 3rd party libraries where they can't be modified.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).load(function() { 

    //script here    });
```

This function will execute once all elements of a page have loaded. Including images.

http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Or this:

```
  (function() {
   var myScript = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
   myScript.src = 'http://mysite.com/script.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertAfter(myScript, s);
  })();
```

This will insert an external script (on the fly) at the end of the page. It will be the last thing that's loaded.

Comment: how does the second snippet guarantee that it will execute AFTER all the ready handlers have been executed ?